# Why is this not a metric on the space of Riemann Integrable functions on [a,b]?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I've just started to teach myself a little on the basics of metric spaces, and came across the following question.

> Let $d_2$ be the pseudo-metric defined on the space of continuous functions
>   on $[a,b]$ by $$d_2(f,g) = \sqrt{\int_a^b{(f(t)-g(t))^2}dt}$$
>
> Why is $d_2$ not a metric on the space of Riemann Integrable functions on [a,b]?

Clearly, for $f,g \in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$,  $d_2$ satisfies $d_2(f,g) = 0$ if and only if $f=g$, and that $d_2(f,g) = d_2(g,f)$.

The problem must thus be that $d_2$ does not always satisfy $d_2(f,g)≤d_2(f,h) + d_2(h,g)$ for $f,g,h \in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$. But what function is Riemann Integrable but not continuous on $[a,b]$ and doesn't satisfy the above inequality?

Comment: In fact $d_2$ is a pseudo metric: it satisfies all axioms of a metric but $d_2(f,g)=0\iff f=g$. To check this it suffices you show that $f\mapsto (\int_a^b |f|^2)^{1/2}$ is a pseudo norm, that is, it satisfies all norm axioms except $\lVert f\rVert =0$ may be true without $f=0$ being true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f$ equal to $1$ at $a$ and to $0$ for $x \in (a,b]$ is Riemann integrable and $$\int_a^b f^2(t) dt =0$$ Hence you have $d_2(f,0)=0$. However $f$ is not always vanishing.

Answer (score 0):

$d_2(f,g)$ is not a distance since if $f,g$ are Riemann integrable function agrees on the interval $[a,b]$ except for many finitely points, then 
$$ \int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bg(x)dx \Longrightarrow \int_a^b(f(x)-g(x) )dx=0,$$ but the functions not coincide everywhere in the interval $[a,b]$ so $f\ne g$.