# A metric between functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I want to measure the distance between functions $f$ and $g$ (not necessarily continuous) on a bounded subset $M\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. I assume $f$ and $g$ are locally integrable and bounded on $M$. Then I define:

$$d(f,g)=\left|\iint_M \left(f(x,y)-g(x,y)\right)dxdy\right|$$

I believe that requiring locally integrability and boundedness is enough to show that $d$ is a metric. Clearly, $d(f,g)\geq 0$, $d(f,g)=d(g,f)$, and $d(f,g)=0$ if and only if $f=g$.

I am struggling to prove the triangle inequality. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392924/why-is-this-not-a-metric-on-the-space-of-riemann-integrable-functions-on-a-b) shows that Riemann integrability is not strong enough for a similar function to be a metric because distinct points can have zero distances. Given that I've assumed local integrability and boundedness, does the triangle inequality hold for $d$?

Comment: Have you looked at $L^p$-spaces?

Comment: You should consult the answers to the question that you are referring to. The problem there is not the triangle inequality but the condition that distinct points have positive distances.

Comment: @Justpassingby Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the absolute value sign within the double integral. It is well possible for the integral of $f-g$ to be zero without $f$ being equal to $g,$ even for the nicest imaginable continuous functions with compact support.

You also need to account for functions that are *almost everywhere* equal - in fact the usual procedure is to define a pseudometric, then factor out the zero distances by considering a metric on *equivalence classes* (modulo equality almost everywhere).

After that the triangle inequality follows from the triangle inequality for the usual absolute value metric on the real numbers and the fact that the integral of a nonnegative function is nonnegative.

As commenter abcdef pointed out, this metric space is a subspace of the complete normed vector space known by the standard name of $L^1(M).$

Comment: So $d$ is a pseudo-metric if the absolute values appear inside the integral, correct?

Comment: Yes it is. (If the absolute values are outside the integral, it is a pseudometric in a near-trivial way, with an excessive number of functions having zero distance to each other)

Comment: Can you also include an example case to demonstrate your point in the 2nd paragraph? I'm wracking my  brain to understand how local integrability doesn't account for that. I probably just don't understand local integrability well, but an example would definitely help.

Comment: A function that is zero everywhere except at one point has distance zero from a function that is zero everywhere. Both are locally integrable (even globally Riemann integrable).

Comment: Perhaps, then I am interested instead with functions that are piecewise continuous. If $f$ and $g$ are piecewise continous functions, then $d$ is a metric (not a pseudo metric), correct?